# Change all dates in postgresql table to previous day

Tags: postgresql, date

I need to go through every row in a table and set every date in a particular column to the date before its current value (minus 14 hours, previous day, etc).
I could write a script to do this but I was wondering if there was a better SQL method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET thefield = thefield - interval '14 hour';
```

relevant docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), which should have been your first place to check.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find that documentation.

Comment: Is it possible de do the same thing on a whole database ? (I mean, without having to make it for every column in every table)